# Java: "iterator" over tuples

Tags: java, iterator, inner-classes

I have a class Students that has a member `bigTable` of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`. If we imagine it a s a matrix, I would like to be able to iterate over a specific column, given as a parameter in some iterator initialization. Also, I would like the iterator to have 2 methods, `getValue` and `getPosition`. i.e. something like:

1 2 3
9 8 6
3 4 5

```
Student student = newStudent()
SomeType(what??) it = student.iterator(1);
it.getValue() // returns 2
it.getPosition() // returns 0
it.next() // moves to next position
it.getValue() // returns 8
it.getPosition() // returns 1
...
```

This interface is just a suggestion. I was thinking about kinda implementing the iterator pattern in Student by doing an inner class. But is it appropriate to return a reference to the inner class?? In fact if I want to pass the iterator as an argument to somebody, what type should I say it is? (inner class is not visible)...

Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this task?

Also, just wondering, if I returned the entire row (an ArrayList, in which case Student could implement the Iterator interface) will it occupy extra memory (I mean will it be copied over or just a reference passed?)

Comment: Just wrap the entire ArrayList of ArrayList in another class -- everything will be passed as a reference, so nothing will be wasted.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning an instance of an inner class is a common way of supplying an `Iterator` - see the `java.util` source code for many examples.

I think deviating from the normal `Iterator` interface would be unnecessarily confusing, especially if you call the method returning it "iterator".

If you want the `iterator()` result to let you get something with `getValue()` and `getPosition()` methods, declare an interface with those methods. I'll call it `ElementData` - you can think of a more meaningful name for your situation. Your `iterator()` method can then return `Iterator<ElementData>`.

Your code would become:

```
Student student = newStudent()
Iterator<ElementData> it = student.iterator(1);
ElementData element;
element = it.next()
element.getValue() // returns 2
element.getPosition() // returns 0
element = it.next() // moves to next position
element.getValue() // returns 8
element.getPosition() // returns 1
```

Comment: So the inner class would implement Iterator?

Comment: Yes - that is the usual pattern for iterator() methods.

Comment: Where are those 2 methods actually implemented?

Comment: You can either make ElementData a public class, and implement them there, or make it an interface and have another nested class implement it. If the position always starts at 0 and increments by one, you could drop it and return a simple Iterator<Integer>.